# Blazor WASM, можно ли избежать перерисовки всей страницы?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-client-side

В App.razor всё как обычно:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                hello world
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>404</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            404
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Так же реализован свой AuthenticationStateProvider.
Вопрос в том, можно ли как-то избежать двойной перерисовки всей страницы, когда меняется авторизация?
Есть сервис, который обновляет JWT токен, после чего новые данные уходят в AuthenticationStateProvider, приложение начинает перерисовывать всю страницу, на которой в данной момент находится, а это еще 1 лишний запрос к API (пока что), что хотелось бы избежать.
В консоли вижу это (запрос на /Login/Refresh - и есть обновление токена, после чего страница перерисовывается (изначально загрузка сделана в методе OnAfterRenderAsync)):
[image: console log]